# Multiple Params REST API call

Tags: rest, api, go

I currently have my routes set for my REST API as:
using mux

localhost:8080/user/{id}
localhost:8080/space/{id}

```
server.Router.HandleFunc("/users", middlewares.SetMiddlewareJSON(server.GetUsers)).Methods("GET")
server.Router.HandleFunc("/posts", middlewares.SetMiddlewareJSON(server.GetPosts)).Methods("GET")
```

the set middleware function

```
func SetMiddlewareJSON(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        next(w, r)
    }
}
```

How would I combine them to become

localhost:8080/user/1/post/{id}

the repository for the project is here:
https://github.com/Robbie-Thomas/fullstack

Comment: Like so `server.Router.HandleFunc("/users/{user_id}/posts/{post_id}", ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a `HandlerFunc` with that path:

```
server.Router.HandleFunc("/users/{userId}/post/{id}", middlewares.SetMiddlewareJSON(server.GetUsers)).Methods("GET")
```

In the handler func, you'll access those variables:

```
vars:=mux.Vars(request)
userId:=vars["userId"]
postId:=vars["id"]
```